# Passing Class Variables through to different tasks in Airflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow

I am having difficulty understanding the implementation of cross-task variable usage while also following airflows best practises

I've created the below example to hopefully demonstrate my issue:

Within my task 'Task_One_Example' I have created an instance of the class 'ExampleClass', this class is initialising using __ init __ to set some variables using the base DAG information (dag_id, run_id) which is then used later within function calls. I am happy with this principle as a whole.

However, if I want to re-use the class variable, it would appear I need to re-create the instance of this class within another task.

DAG Python:

```
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow2_utils import environment_scheduler
from os import environ
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pendulum

#Default settings applied to all tasks
default_args = {
    'catchup': False,
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1)
}

@dag(
    start_date=datetime(2023, 2, 21, tzinfo=pendulum.timezone("Europe/London")),
    schedule_interval=None,
    default_args=default_args,
    tags=["Client: Test", "Version: 2.2.5"]
)

def test_dag():

    start = DummyOperator(
        task_id='start'
    )

    @task(task_id='Task_One_Example')
    def test_one():
        import PythonClassTest as pct

        classInstance = pct.exampleClass
        classInstance.print_dag_info()
        
    @task(task_id='Task_Two_Example')
    def test_two():
        import PythonClassTest as pct

        classInstance = pct.exampleClass
        classInstance.print_dag_info()
        
    end = DummyOperator(
        task_id='end'
    )

    start >> test_one() >> test_two() >> end

dag = test_dag()
```

External Class:

```
from airflow.operators.python import get_current_context

class exampleClass():
    def __init__(self):

        context = get_current_context()
        ti = context['ti']

        self.dag_id = ti.dag_id
        self.run_id = ti.run_id

    def print_dag_info(self):

        context = get_current_context()
        ti = context['ti']
        task_id = ti.task_id

        print("""
        dag_id: {}
        run_id: {}
        task_id: {}
        """.format(self.dag_id, self.run_id, task_id))
```

I had initially toyed with the idea of using XCOMs to pull/push the data, but from my understanding this these are mostly only appropriate for smaller variables, and depending on the size of the class this could become significantly less scalable.

The second thought would be to initialize the class variable out-with with any DAG task, but this goes against best practises, and would have a detrimental effect as it would result in the variable continuously being re-initialised.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your use-case ? Also, XCOMs can be used for larger datasets as well. You will just need to use XCoM Backend for that which relies on external Cloud Storage.

Comment: @manmeet, sure sure - the intended use case for the above would mostly come from a logging perspective. A lot of the tasks I would be using would focus on connecting to SFTP destinations to retrieve or place files. To keep a track of what completes under each task we log info directly to Bigquery tables, storing info such as dag_id, run_id etc. In an ideal word the functions for SFTP connectivity (and sub functions for logging) live under the same class as they use mostly the same parameters.

Comment: I should add - and this is my fault for not initially highlighting my intent, what I am attempting to do is remove the requirement of repeatedly calling the code 'classInstance = pct.exampleClass' within each task, with the idea that I'd only like to call this once - and then simply be able use 'classInstance' wherever appropriate

Comment: Have you considered implementing a custom decorator that performs the class initialization for the task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to look at the problem in two different ways.

1. Purpose is solely to get the combination of `dag_id`, `dag_run_id`, `task_id` to get details on when a particular DAG, it's instance and it's tasks completed/failed/succeeded.

If this is the use-case, you should try using Airflow's REST API: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#tag/DAGRun and https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#tag/TaskInstance

You can even create a report out of it using a DAG.

2. OR if the purpose of this to show just as an example and you want to instantiate a similar class that needs to be re-used in each task and print the details in the log, you should be using `on_success_callback` or `on_failure_callback` ([Reference](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/logging-monitoring/callbacks.html)).

Hope this makes sense.